# Should I say the morning blessing on head covering even if I don't cover my head?

Tags: halacha, blessing, tznius-modesty, kippa-yarmulka, hair-covering

Should unmarried women--and all those who do not cover their heads for whatever reason--still say the morning blessing "otayr yisro-ayl b'siforo" ("Who crowns Israel with splendor"), referring to head covering? Or would this be a bracha levatala?

Comment: I seem to recall hearing that the Rambam said someone who's blind should still stay *pokeach ivrim*, which seems similar, but I can't source it.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30663/759

Comment: @MonicaCellio I find the Rambam's having said that unlikely. Many other Rishonim, yes.

Comment: @DoubleAA I could well be mistaken about whose name I heard it in (or whether it had a credible pedigree at all).

Comment: @monica rambam follows the gamoro which says to say the barochoth hasha7ar at home as the process is being done not in shul. Therefore if you put on clothes you make the barocho if you slept in your clothes you don't make a barocho. Also since most modern cities doesn't have a rooster cockadoodaling, we don't say lasachbi barocho.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob The gemara never says the brachot have to be said at home.

Comment: @DoubleAA obviously if you are sleeping outside your house you can say it there as well. the whole point is to say it then do it.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob That is one understanding of the Gemara. It's not the only coherent read.

Comment: @DoubleAA rambam clearly says they are in the wrong. rambam :)

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob amram gaon clearly says he is in the wrong. amram :)

Comment: @DoubleAA let me see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31432/759) it is a [machloket](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/587/759) rishonim if the blessing עוטר ישראל בתפארה is made by each individual on their own personal benefit, or if it is made on the general customs of the world. This same machloket should apply in your case as well.