# Do you need to say Krias Shema Shel Hamitah if you don't go to sleep at night?

Tags: halacha, shema, sleep

If you work the night shift and always go to sleep during the day do you say Krias Shema Shel Hamitah?

Edit: Question is mostly about the actual Shema, the brachos seems like people mostly saying you don't say them.

Comment: The commonly accepted Chumra on Shavuot is to hear all the regular daily blessings from someone else just in case one is exempt due to not sleeping. The simplerl reading of nearly all Rishonim though (except notably Rambam) is that one says the blessings even if not doing the action https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31432/759

Comment: @DoubleAA what about the actual shema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has to sleep in the day then the Rema Orach Chaim 231,1 brings an opinion that one only says "Vihi Noam" to protect from Mazikin:

> אם אי אפשר לו ללמוד בלא שינת צהריים – יישן. ויש אומרים שיקרא קודם שיישן ויהי נועם

But the Mishna Brura quotes the Levush that you don't say anything

> ויהי נועם - משום סכנת מזיקין. וכתב הלבוש שאין נוהגין כן:

As for Bircat Hamapil you don't say it when sleeping during the day as stated in the Biur Halacha Orach Chaim 231,1

> על שינת היום לא נתקנה הברכה לענין ברכת המפיל נראה דעבר זמן שהרי אינו יכול לומר השכיבנו אחר עה"ש כדאיתא שם בגמרא וממילא בעיניננו ג"כ אינו יכול לומר שתשכיבני לשלום שאין עוד הזמן של תחלת שכיבה אלא סוף שכיבה

The Kriat Shema of the morning must be said but does not need to repeated when sleeping during the day as this is not the regular time for sleeping for the average person and Chazal did not make exeptions for nocturnal workers

Comment: Wow that's totally not how I understood the question. Maybe you're right. I thought he wanted to know if you say it anyway at night even if not sleeping. You answered if he says it before sleeping but during the day.

Comment: Don't understand this answer. I'm not asking about the two daily (morning and evening) required shema.

Comment: I have tried to address your concerns @larry909